# BarPlot showing tip only on 1 bar

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

```
aspect_rank_df

                                                     Rating
The diversity of the company or organization        7.640009
The financial performance or funding status of      6.673524
The industry that I’d be working in                 6.397089
How widely used or impactful the product            6.057804
The specific department or team I’d be working on   5.906875
The opportunity to work from home/remotely          5.673181
The office environment or company culture           4.407196
Opportunities for professional development          4.225200
The specific department or team I’d be working on   4.065791
The compensation and benefits offered               3.953243

plt.subplots(figsize = (8, 6))
plt.title("Job Opportunity Aspects Rating", fontsize = 15)
sns.barplot(x = aspect_rank_df['Rating'], y = aspect_rank_df.index)
```

This gives me required barchart but it shows a tip only on `purple` bar and I don't want that. Tell me how to `remove` it and why it `appears`?

[image]

Comment: The sentence "The specific department or team I’d be working on" appears twice in your list. Hence the violet bar shows the mean of the two numbers and the black line shows the errorbar for the mean. To remove the errorbar, remove one of the "The specific department or team I’d be working on" from your dataframe.

Comment: My bad! Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest for pointing out.